# PHP does not load

Tags: php, apache2

im trying to Start PHP on my Webserver, but this is all im getting

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled#  a2enmod php8.1
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php8.1:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
ERROR: Module mpm_prefork not properly enabled: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.load is a real file, not touching it
ERROR: Could not enable dependency mpm_prefork for php8.1, aborting
```

any clue how to proceed?

Thanks :)

Starting php, and i was expecting it to start.

Comment: check the modules you have ebalbed vai a2enmod and see which module is causing this error and try to disable that module. If no module is there try : sudo a2dismod mpm_event

Comment: Module mpm_event already disabled and i cant disable prefork i get this ERROR: The following modules depend on mpm_prefork and need to be disabled first: php8.0